# How to force web app on Azure to work with .net Framework 4.5.2?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-framework-version

My web app was running without any problem with web app referring to .net framework 4.5.2 earlier.

But after Azure portal decided to make a shift to .net framework 4.6, my application started giving exception.

I have entry for  but that does not seems to be working.
Any way by which I can force web app to use .net framework 4.5.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A given VM can only have one version of the .NET 4.x framework, and at present Azure App Service has 4.6.2 (and soon 4.7)

Note that it has had 4.6 or higher for several years, so I suspect your issue is not directly related to this.

If you think you do have a situation where something that worked on 4.5.2 breaks on 4.6.2, I encourage you top post a separate question. But the answer to this question is that you don't control the 4.x version running on App Service.